# How to generate random 1s and 0s in a matrix array?

Tags: python

I have a matrix and it's currently populated with just 1's. How do I make it so it populates with random 1's and 0's?

```
matrix5x5 = [[1 for row in range (5)] for col in range (5)]

for row in matrix5x5:
    for item in row:
        print(item,end=" ")
    print()
print("")
```

Output:

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

I want something like:

```
1 0 0 1 0
0 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 0 1
1 1 0 0 1
0 1 1 1 1
```

I found something regarding using `random.randint(0,1)` but I don't know how to change my current code to include the above.

Comment: Do you know what part of this code specifies the value to be placed in each element of the matrix?  Once you do, replace that with the expression you found to compute a random number.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.randint(2, size=(5, 5))
array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Numpy arrays support most list operations that involve indexing and iteration, and if you really care, you can turn it back into a list:

```
>>> np.random.randint(2, size=(5, 5)).tolist()
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

And, if for some strange reason, you are 100% adamant on using vanilla Python, just use the `random` module and a list comprehension:

```
>>> import random
>>> [[random.randint(0,1) for j in range (5)] for i in range (5)]
[[0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you :) is there anyway to do it without numpy though?

Comment: @JonathanRoss I edited to include a vanilla solution.

Comment: @JonathanRoss No problem. Please remember to accept the answer that you felt was most helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 2):

Modifying your code, using the `random` package (and not the `numpy` equivalent):

```
matrix5x5 = [[random.randint(0,1) for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(5)]

for row in matrix5x5: 
    for item in row:
        print(item,end=" ") 
    print()
print("")

0 1 0 0 1 
0 1 0 1 0 
0 0 1 1 0 
0 0 0 1 0 
1 0 0 1 1
```

But honestly, `numpy` makes it a lot faster and easier!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use numpy. Do the following:

```
import numpy as np
my_matrix = np.random.randint(2,size=(5,5))
```

This will create a random 5 by 5 matrix with 0s and 1s.

Comment: No. That will give all zeros.

Comment: Oops. Fixed that.